# Simple Login Web (Google): Missing `email` and `thirdPartyUserData` when using `preferRedirect: true`: bug or intended (undocumented) restriction?

Tags: firebase

I'm using 'Simple Login Web' with Google, and I discovered that in the auth callback, the `email` property is missing and the `thirdPartyUserData` object is empty when I set `preferRedirect` to `true`.

This is either:

- a bug in Firebase
- a bug in my own code that I should fix myself (see code below. also, the configuration at Google is done exactly as instructed at https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-google.html)
- a known restriction that needs to be documented

So, my question is: Which? And if it's a bug in my own code, how do I fix it?

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://<myfirebase>.firebaseio.com/');
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(ref, function(error, user) {
    // When logging in with `preferRedirect: true`, `user` contains:
    // * accessToken
    // * displayName
    // * firebaseAuthToken
    // * id
    // * provider
    // * thirdPartyUserData: empty object
    // * uid
    //
    // When logging in WITHOUT `preferRedirect`, `user` contains:
    // * accessToken
    // * displayName
    // * email
    // * firebaseAuthToken
    // * id
    // * provider
    // * thirdPartyUserData:
    //   * email
    //   * family_name
    //   * gender
    //   * given_name
    //   * hd
    //   * id
    //   * link
    //   * locale
    //   * name
    //   * picture
    //   * verified_email
    // * uid
});

auth.login('google', {
    preferRedirect: true,
    rememberMe: true,
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
});
```

Comment: [Engineer at Firebase] Sounds like a bug! I'll look into it and report back to you here.

Comment: This should be resolved - apologies for the trouble!

Comment: Yes, the response data is correct now. Thanks!