# Firebase google auth bug? Email property missing from user object

Tags: firebase

```
var fbUsers = new Firebase('https://my-FB-subdomain.firebaseio.com/users');

var fbAuth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(fbUsers, function(error, user) {

});
fbAuth.login('google');
```

The docs say that the [user object should have an `email` property](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-google.html#after-authenticating), but the user object passed to that callback has these properties (no `email` property in the root level):

```
id
uid
displayName
provider
thirdPartyUserData
 - id
 - email
 - verified_email
 - name
 - given_name
 - family_name
 - link
 - picture
 - gender
 - locale
verified_email
name
given_name
family_name
link
picture
gender
locale
accessToken
firebaseAuthToken
```

Comment: perhaps related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350642/simple-login-web-google-missing-email-and-thirdpartyuserdata-when-using

Comment: Is this issue ongoing for you? We pushed out a few changes today, and Google authentication was impacted, as you noted, for a few hours, though should be fully resolved. Please let me know if this is ongoing, and in general, I would recommend reaching out to support@firebase.com for the fastest support turnaround.